# Next image crashing on other devices but working on mine only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js

I am trying to use next image and it works perfectly on my device but it crashes on every other device. Here is the jsx:

```
                    <div className="img-container-homePage">
                        <Image src="/catI.jpg" alt="Cat" layout="fill" />
                    </div>
```

and here is the css:

```
      .img-container-homePage {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 90vh;
          z-index: -1;
          filter: brightness(0.5) contrast(0.7) saturate(80%) hue-rotate(10deg);
}
```

The image crashes and shows alt on other devices. there is a problem in loading the image here is my directories:
[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbrNa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Image tag src should be "/images/catI.jpg" according to your directories.

Comment: THANK YOUUUU so much i thought nextjs did it by itself and never thought of the most simple thing at all and wasted 4 days on this! THANK YOUUUUU

Comment: Still cant tell why it worked on your device, maybe a cache thing, anyway glad its solved :)